# How to structure a Grunt task for develop and release

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-cssmin

I cant really seem to figure out how to structure the config for a certain task. Currently I'm trying to do this for `cssmin`.

This config snippet works fine:

```
cssmin: {
    options: {
        shorthandCompacting: false,
        roundingPrecision: -1
    },
    target: {
        files: {
            'wwwroot/all.css': ['bower_components/animate/animate.css']
        }
    }
},
```

And I'm running this like so:

```
grunt.registerTask('Test', ['cssmin']);
```

But I want create a *develop* and *release* config for this. So I tried the following config styles, all of them said `Done, without errors.`, but none of the configs created a file.

```
cssmin: {
    options: {
        shorthandCompacting: false,
        roundingPrecision: -1
    },
    dev: {
        target: {
            files: {
                'wwwroot/all.css': ['bower_components/animate/animate.css']
            }
        }
    }
}
grunt.registerTask('Test', ['cssmin:dev']);
```

And like this:

```
cssmin: {
    dev: {
        options: {
            shorthandCompacting: false,
            roundingPrecision: -1
        },
        target: {
            files: {
                'wwwroot/all.css': ['bower_components/animate/animate.css']
            }
        }
    }
}
grunt.registerTask('Test', ['cssmin:dev']);
```

But those configs don't seem to work. They save `Done, without errors.`, but it isn't creating a CSS file like the first config example does.

So isn't this the way you should create a different `dev`/`release` type of config? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `cssmin:dev`, dev is your target. there is no need to specify the `target` propriety w/in it again. try this:

```
cssmin: {
    dev: {
        options: {
            shorthandCompacting: false,
            roundingPrecision: -1
        },
        files: {
            'wwwroot/all.css': ['bower_components/animate/animate.css']
        }
    },
    build : {
        options: {
            shorthandCompacting: true,
            roundingPrecision: -1
        },
        files: {
            'wwwroot/all.min.css': ['bower_components/animate/animate.css']
        }
    }
}
grunt.registerTask('Test', ['cssmin:dev']);
```